# Writing subqueries instead of Joins MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Here I have 2 tables in the a_bkorders database.

```
mysql> select *
    -> from customers;
+---------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------------+----------------`enter code here`
| cust_id | cust_name_last | cust_name_first | cust_state | cust_postal_code | 
+---------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------------+----------------
```

and

```
mysql> select *
    -> from order_headers;
+----------+------------+---------+
| order_id | order_date | cust_id |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

I need to show the cust_id, the cust_name and the number of order (count(order_id) as 'number of orders) but by using using subqueries, not joins.

This this what I wrote:

```
SELECT cust_id, cust_name_last,'number of orders'
FROM 
    (
    SELECT cu.cust_id, cu.cust_name_last, count(oh.order_id) as 'number of orders'
    FROM a_bkorders.customers cu
    JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh ON cu.cust_id = oh.cust_id
    WHERE cu.cust_state in ('NJ', 'MA')
    ) A;
```

and I get:

```
+---------+----------------+------------------+
| cust_id | cust_name_last | number of orders |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
|  208950 | Adams          | number of orders |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
```

But if I run the subquery alone, I only get 1 row out. (I know there are plenty)

```
+---------+----------------+------------------+
| cust_id | cust_name_last | number of orders |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
|  208950 | Adams          |               70 |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
```

So my question is why is the subquery alone only spits out one row instead of multiple rows. Also, am i joining the two tables correctly with a subquery and why do I get `number of orders` when I run the whole query?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Didi

Comment: after you rename the 'number of orders' you select it in sql you cannot do that. it returns the name of the name you selected.

Comment: you mean this:SELECT cust_id, cust_name_last, 'number of orders'
FROM 
 (
 SELECT cu.cust_id, cu.cust_name_last, count(oh.order_id)
 FROM a_bkorders.customers cu
 JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh ON cu.cust_id = oh.cust_id
 WHERE cu.cust_state in ('NJ', 'MA')
 ) A; ? It still shows "number of orders"

Comment: that's because you try to double select the cust_id, and cust_name_last where it is already selected. If you do 
SELECT 'number of orders' FROM ( SELECT cu.cust_id, cu.cust_name_last, count(oh.order_id) FROM a_bkorders.customers cu JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh ON cu.cust_id = oh.cust_id WHERE cu.cust_state in ('NJ', 'MA') ) A; is this what you want?

Comment: But this mean the outer query only has one column 'number of orders'. I have to get 3 columns with the id and name. This frustrating because the parameters of the outer query are not all from one table but two different ones.

Comment: why do you use 2 query at all. what are you trying to accomplish, I don't think I understand your question. If you are selecting 3 columns then why not just have sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you would want to correct in your query

- In the sub-query, give a clear alias for the count variable instead of 'number of orders' and
- Use that alias as the column name to be displayed (name the alias as you want to display)
- most importantly use the `group by` clause to get the desired results (you are using an aggregate count)

Below is the modified query,

```
SELECT cust_id, cust_name_last, count as 'number of orders'
FROM 
(
SELECT cu.cust_id, cu.cust_name_last, count(oh.order_id) as count
FROM a_bkorders.customers cu
JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh ON cu.cust_id = oh.cust_id
WHERE cu.cust_state in ('NJ', 'MA')
GROUP BY oh.cust_id
) A;
```

Hope this helps!